# Replace part of a parent-theme customizer in the child-theme

Tags: php, child-theme, pluggable

I'm created a child-theme of the [OnePress theme](https://www.famethemes.com/themes/onepress/) and would like to update a part of the `inc/customizer.php` function. Specifically, the theme customizer adds the following control:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    new Onepress_Customize_Repeatable_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'onepress_hero_images',
        array(
            'label'     => esc_html__('Background Images', 'onepress'),
            'description'   => '',
            'priority'     => 40,
            'section'       => 'onepress_hero_images',
            'title_format'  => esc_html__( 'Background', 'onepress'), // [live_title]
            'max_item'      => 2, // Maximum item can add

            'fields'    => array(
                'image' => array(
                    'title' => esc_html__('Background Image', 'onepress'),
                    'type'  =>'media',
                    'default' => array(
                        'url' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/hero5.jpg',
                        'id' => ''
                    )
                ),

            ),

        )
    )
);
```

I've made a child theme and would like to update the `max_item` parameter to `5` from within the child theme. The above code forms part of a huge function, of which I only want to change a small part. I don't know if the original container function

```
function onepress_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
  // lots of stuff here
}
```

is pluggable or not.

How can I change just that specific piece of code from within the child theme?